# If/else statement on page.php not rendering 1 of 2 conditionals

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics, conditional-statements

Mind you, I'm new to php and wordpress.

I need to render 2 different google adwords scripts on my wordpress site. After much research I concluded that the most effective solution was a conditional inside page.php that parses the page_id and injects the corresponding code if the conditional is met.

I need to inject one script into Pages A, B, and C. I've been able to make this work just fine.

However, I also need to inject another script into Page X. This utilizes the same code -- but for whatever reason it is not working.

I realize there may be other issues at play to make this script injection not possible, but I wanted to ask the community if there is something fundamentally wrong with my php syntax or logic.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
// THIS WORKS
<?php if ( is_page( array( 600,601,602 ))) { ?>
    <!-- Google Code for Pages A, B, and C -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var google_conversion_id = 999999999;
        var google_conversion_language = "en";
        var google_conversion_format = "3";
        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
        var google_conversion_label = "afafafafafafafaf";
        var google_remarketing_only = false;
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/99999999/?label=asdafasfafafafaf&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
        </div>
    </noscript>
<?php } ?>

// THIS DOESN'T WORK
<?php if ( is_page( array( 700 ))) { ?>
    <!-- Google Code for Page X -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var google_conversion_id = 9999999999;
        var google_conversion_language = "en";
        var google_conversion_format = "3";
        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
        var google_conversion_label = "ljljkjjljjljljljjkl";
        var google_remarketing_only = false;
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/99999999999/?label=ljljkjjljjljljljjkl&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
        </div>
    </noscript>
<?php } ?>
```

I've also tried to join them into if/elsif/else statements but that breaks both of them.

I've rearranged the order where the 3-page array is on bottom, and the 3-page continues to work, but the 1-page still does not work.

Any feedback that may help me to solve this is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is your snippet literally a snippet of your source, or are you combining two separate sources/source blocks? Is there caching that could be preventing this from working correctly?

Comment: i've entered the code as it appears in my question above, sans the //this works/doesn't work commentary. so yes, both of these scripts appear in the page.php. caching doesn't seem to be the issue as i've been cache-busting

Answer (score 0):

Don't use array when you're not using one.

Also try this:

```
<?php if ( is_page( array( 600,601,602 ))) { ?>
    <!-- Google Code for Pages A, B, and C -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var google_conversion_id = 999999999;
        var google_conversion_language = "en";
        var google_conversion_format = "3";
        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
        var google_conversion_label = "afafafafafafafaf";
        var google_remarketing_only = false;
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/99999999/?label=asdafasfafafafaf&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
        </div>
    </noscript>
<?php } elseif ( is_page(700)) { ?>
    <!-- Google Code for Page X -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var google_conversion_id = 9999999999;
        var google_conversion_language = "en";
        var google_conversion_format = "3";
        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
        var google_conversion_label = "ljljkjjljjljljljjkl";
        var google_remarketing_only = false;
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/99999999999/?label=ljljkjjljjljljljjkl&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
        </div>
    </noscript>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. this was my original code. i switched it to an array just to see if it had something to do with my non-array syntax, since the array was working just fine. regardless, an array with one value in it isn't the problem. at this point i'm thinking that it's a plugin or something else that's preventing adwords from being rendered (not adblock -- i've disabled that).

Comment: Are you seeing the JS in the source (not in inspector, but the actual `view-source:http://yourdomain.com/path/to/file`?)

Comment: And also, are you 100% sure you're using the correct page ID's? Try using `die(var_dump(get_the_ID()))` if you're in the loop just to make sure.